# Why after load seccomp filter, PING will no work by normal user

Tags: c, linux, seccomp

I use seccomp record 'ping' used syscall. When I run it, it always notice

> socket: Operation not permitted.

I can run ping in bash very well, but no work after load seccomp filter in program.

But if I run the same program by root, it will run very well.

This is running in Ubuntu 18.04 with 4.15.0-54-generic kernel.

I have tried use Root user to run the program, then in the child progress, I use setuid(1000) to set to a normal user, and it still no work.

If I not use fork, it still notice no premitted.

If I change the seccomp default action to SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, it still no work too.

Here is a simple code by C.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <seccomp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void child() {
        setuid(1000);
        scmp_filter_ctx ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_LOG);

        if (seccomp_load(ctx) != 0) {
                printf("SCMP LAOD ERR!");
        } else {
                seccomp_release(ctx);
        }
        execl("/bin/ping", "ping", "-c", "1", "172.16.1.1", NULL);
        printf("EXEC FAIL");
}
int main(){

        int p = fork();
        if (p < 0) {
                printf("Frok ERROR!");
                exit(1);
        }
        if ( p == 0 ) {
                child();
        } else {
                struct rusage usage;
                int status;
                if (wait4(p, &status, WSTOPPED, &usage) == -1) {
                        kill(p, SIGKILL);
                }
        }
}
```

I use `gcc main.c -o main.out -lseccomp` to compile it.

English is not my first Language, I'm sorry about my grammar.

Comment: Not sure, but [The inherent fragility of seccomp()](https://lwn.net/Articles/738694/) caught my eye. (from those who know the Linux kernel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ping` only works as root. Normally it runs as root because it has the setuid bit set in its file permissions:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44168 May  8  2014 /bin/ping
   ^         ^^^^
   |
this 's' is called 'setuid' and means it wants to run as the user which owns it, which is root
```

You cannot use seccomp unless you are root, or you set the [no_new_privs flag](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/no_new_privs.html). You are not using seccomp directly, but through a library. It appears the library is setting the flag for you.

The no_new_privs flag means that you cannot run setuid programs. Well, you can run them, but they won't be setuid. They'll run as your user. Which doesn't have permission to send special packets the way `ping` requires. So `ping` fails because it doesn't have permission to ping.

Comment: Learned more about `seccomp` and the `no_new_privs` flag than I knew before, thank you.

Comment: You are right, but I found that the ``` mtr ``` command  permissioni is ``` -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 73664 Nov  2  2017 /usr/bin/mtr ```, and when I run it in the program, it notice ' Failure to open IPv4 sockets: Operation not permitted'. Do you know any thing about it?

Comment: @boxjan `mtr` execs `mtr-packet` which is setuid

Comment: @immibis Thank you for your answer sincerely, but I noted another thing, I use `strace ping 192.168.1.1 -c 1`, it still have no permission, but `strace mtr -r ping` is working well. I think strace do not set `no_new_privs_flag` , I try use `strace -ff strace -ff ping 192.168.1.1 -c 1` to trace it, I can't find any thing `prctl` call.

Comment: @boxjan strace calls ptrace (and doesn't show the ptrace) and ptrace'd processes also can't use setuid. It's a different flag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I learned more about `ptrace` and `seccomp`, thank you.